# Como alterar valores de posição para determinado recurso?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro, fórmula

Mais um desafio Hardcore, não sei se vou saber explicar bem, mas ai vai.
Na tabela abaixo, eu tenho o recurso "X", onde ele já efetuou 8 contatos( 5 concluídos e 3 não concluídos) e eu gostaria de contar automaticamente qual é o próximo contato que ele irá realizar retirando os 8 casos em que ele já realizou o contato. Na tabela também há a posição para contato que seria a sequencia de contato que deveria seguir mas essa coluna sempre vem com erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito obrigado por qualquer ajuda ou troca de conhecimento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com estes dados de teste:

[image: Dados de exemplo]

Você pode realizar isto com o seguinte código, em que a explicação está no comentário:

```
Sub teste()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim UltimaLinha As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim matriz() As Variant
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
    i = 1
    With ws
        'Mostra dados se estiverem filtrados
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
        'Última linha da coluna A
        UltimaLinha = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Filtra o campo 3 do intervalo [A1:D & ultimalinha], ou seja, filtra a coluna C para valores diferentes de Concluída e Não Concluída
        .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(UltimaLinha, "D")).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>Concluída", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>Não Concluída"
        'Ordena os valores filtrados
        .Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("D1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                                        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        'Se houver após o filto, msgbox do primeiro valor
        If .Range("A2:A" & UltimaLinha).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 0 Then
            For Each c In .Range("A2:A" & UltimaLinha).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                If i = 1 Then
                    MsgBox c
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Next c
        End If
    'Mostra dados se estiverem filtrados
    If .FilterMode Then
        .ShowAllData
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Cara, resolveu como se fosse nada haha, muito obrigado pela ajuda compartilhada.